# Multiple file upload with Google Closure Library

Tags: swfupload, google-closure, plupload, yui3, google-closure-library

How to handle multiple file uploads with Google Closure?

- Is it possible to use [YUI3 Uploader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/) with [Google Closure
  Library](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/)? Is there an externs file available for YUI3? Would it be
  possible to put the YUI3 Uploader in an iframe and access a variable
  returned by the upload handler in the parent frame of the iframe?
  With an iframe maybe I could create an isolated environment for the
  YUI uploader.
- Does anyone have experience with [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/), [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) or
  another alternative using Google Closure Library?
- As an alternative, I could use [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) to upload files to Google Drive, and then use the Google Drive SDK to download these files to my web host. The drawback is that I can't change the style of Google Picker to match with the style of my web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually fairly easy to write a Google Closure Library component that uses SWFUpload for multiple file uploading. I created an externs file for advanced compilation with the Closure Compiler:

```
var SWFUpload = {
    "instances": function () {},
    "movieCount": {},
    "version": {},
    "QUEUE_ERROR": {
        "QUEUE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED": {},
        "FILE_EXCEEDS_SIZE_LIMIT": {},
        "ZERO_BYTE_FILE": {},
        "INVALID_FILETYPE": {}
    },
    "UPLOAD_ERROR": {
        "HTTP_ERROR": {},
        "MISSING_UPLOAD_URL": {},
        "IO_ERROR": {},
        "SECURITY_ERROR": {},
        "UPLOAD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED": {},
        "UPLOAD_FAILED": {},
        "SPECIFIED_FILE_ID_NOT_FOUND": {},
        "FILE_VALIDATION_FAILED": {},
        "FILE_CANCELLED": {},
        "UPLOAD_STOPPED": {}
    },
    "FILE_STATUS": {
        "QUEUED": {},
        "IN_PROGRESS": {},
        "ERROR": {},
        "COMPLETE": {},
        "CANCELLED": {}
    },
    "BUTTON_ACTION": {
        "SELECT_FILE": {},
        "SELECT_FILES": {},
        "START_UPLOAD": {},
        "JAVASCRIPT": {}
    },
    "CURSOR": {
        "ARROW": {},
        "HAND": {}
    },
    "WINDOW_MODE": {
        "WINDOW": {},
        "TRANSPARENT": {},
        "OPAQUE": {}
    },
    "completeURL": function () {},
    "Console": {
        "writeLine": function () {}
    }
},
FileProgress = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the `goog.net.iframeIo` class in the Google Closure Library? You could render several file input elements in individual forms, then, using this component, post each of those forms via hidden IFrames to the web server.

Here's a link to Google's documentation on how to implement it:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/net/iframeio.js#48

Comment: The user can't select multiple files at once with this solution. I will use this approach for single file uploads, but keep looking for a solution for multiple file uploads.